# Output from "wbinfo --user-groups USER" and "wbinfo --group-info GROUP" do not match

Tags: samba, winbind

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 with winbindd/smbd version 3.6.23-20.0.1.el6.

I created some new AD groups and added existing users.  I used this command:

```
wbinfo --group-info <GROUP>
```

My username is correctly listed.  However, when I use this command:

```
wbinfo --user-groups <USER>
```

I see the GID's for all the groups I am a member but it does not include the new group I just added myself.  Consequently, I am denied permissions to access a directory with an ACL that uses this new AD group.

However, I have a second user who was also added to the new AD group.  The GID appears in their list of groups and they are able to access the same directory.